# Can any tell me the difference between CSR version and certificate version?

Tags: certificate, openssl, x509certificate, x509, x509certificate2

I want to generate a X509 v3 certificate using a CSR (RFC2986), but the RFC says PKCS10 (CSR) supports only v1. Can anyone tell me the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PKCS#10 version field does not refer to the version of the requested X.509 certificate.

The version field is used to describe the format of the subsequent ASN.1 object. A correct decoder should read the version first and then decodes the rest of the encoded object fields according to this value.

Current formats:

- X509 certificates version is 3
- PKCS#10 CSR version is 1